# How to change behavior of CTRL+L in my terminal?

Tags: manjaro, scrolling, konsole

My current system:

- OS: Manjaro 20.0.3 Lysia
- Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.4.52-1-MANJARO
- Shell: bash 5.0.18
- DE: KDE 5.72.0 / Plasma 5.19.3

Every time I press `CTRL+L` on my terminal (Konsole), the visible content on window is cleaned and my cursor is in first line, it is fine but that cleaned content is really ERASED, so when I try scrolling back that content is not and **I don't wish that behavior**. I've checked *Shortcuts* in `Settings` and I didn't find any action bound with `CTRL+L`. How can I change permanently this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See `bind -p | grep C-l`

Comment: Output is: `"\C-l": clear-screen`, so what should I do to get my goal?

Comment: I told you where the binding is defined. As for changing the behavior: I confirm `konsole` loses content. I use `tmux` and its buffer seems to be immune. Use `tmux` maybe.

Comment: Where the problem occurs, what is the output of `echo "$TERM"`? What is the output of `infocmp -1 | grep -o 'clear=.*'`?

Comment: `xterm-256color` and `clear=\E[H\E[2J,` respectively.